# How to connect nearby places in google maos according to our current location? The places(hospitals,restaurants) are layed in check box

Tags: google-maps, android-intent

1.One page contains check boxes of places(restaurant,hospitals etc...)
2.On check,the map with desired places should display.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've got the map with current location.But I want to get nearby places which is checked in a check box. The check box contains restaurants,police stations,hospitals,petrol pumps etc..

Answer (score 2):

try Google places api it will give you stuff related with places
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/